Heroku sync with GitHub repo
I am planning to deploy a project to Heroku soon.
I saw that it's possible to automatically deploy my app to Heroku after a push on GitHub, and that's a part of what I need. But for the other part, which is to push changes made directly from server (I am using Strapi in my project) automatically to my GitHub repo, I have trouble to find the right way to do it.
Thanks!
